# Powershell throws conversion exception when trying to use SMO.Backup.AddDevice

Tags: sql, powershell, type-conversion, smo, database-restore

I'm completely confused by this one. I'm trying to write a simple database restore script using SMO assemblies.

When I try to add a device and pass the path, like this:

```
$backup.Devices.AddDevice($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
```

I get an odd exception:

> Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "File", for "AddDevice" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType": "Cannot convert value "File" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType". Error: "Invalid cast from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Mana
>   gement.Smo.DeviceType' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType'.""
>   At D\Automatisk inläsning\AutoImportPowershell.ps1:41 char:26
>   + $backup.Devices.AddDevice <<<< ($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Here is the complete script:

```
#ASSEMBLIES:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

#HARDCODED VARIABLES:
$path = "C:\TestFolder\Bakfile.bak"
$server = "(local)"
$databas = "MyDatabase"

#SMO OBJECTS:
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($server)
$res = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore
$backup = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup

#STARTING RESTORE:
$backup.Devices.AddDevice($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$backup.Database = $databas
$backup.Action = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupActionType]::Database
$backup.Initialize = $TRUE
$backup.SqlBackup($srv)

$res.Devices.AddDevice($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$res.Database = $databas
$res.NoRecovery = $TRUE
$res.SqlRestore($srv)
```

What confuses me is the error message itself Invalid cast from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Mana
gement.Smo.DeviceType' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType'. Those sound like the same types to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test adding :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
Add-Type -AssemblyName  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
```

At the end of your `#ASSEMBLIES:` group.

Then  Replace :

```
$backup.Devices.AddDevice($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
```

with

```
$bdi = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem($path, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$backup.Devices.Add($bdi)
```

BackupDeviceItem

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It now works! However, I believe it's because I tried running ISE with administrative privileges...

Comment: Odd that the lack of privileges generated that type of error. Now I have a new ambigious error "Backup failed for server <servername>". No further information. Type is MethodInvocationException

Comment: Perhaps create a new question for a better audience.

Comment: I have accepted your answer correct as my original issue was resolved. Thanks again!